# Prevent multiple times loading stylesheet module

Tags: module, custom-module

I have made a couple of modules that loads their own stylesheet. Why I do that is because then I can optimize my website furhter and only load the stylesheet data when the module is actually on the page. But the problem is is that when I load multiple same modules but with different data it will load the stylesheet twice. Is there anything I can do to prevent that?

```
// Get the document object
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

// Get the module object
$module1 = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_commercial');

// Extract the module base path
$moduleBase = JUri::base() . 'modules/' . $module1->module . '/';

// Define the path of your CSS file dynamically
$cssFile = $moduleBase . 'css/style.css';

$doc->addStyleSheet($cssFile);
```

This is the code I use in my main module file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Assuming it's the same file, only one `<link rel="stylesheet"...>` tag appears.

Comment: Ah i'm a bit stupid, i haven't put that in the main file but in the template file